# Choose the right step-by-step guide, based on your current operating system

Tags: installation, mac

I am confused... So I am trying to install ubuntu on a netbook that has been plagued by viruses.  The confusion I have is... I currently have an Imac that I am using to download ubuntu.  I then want to mount ubuntu onto a flash drive from my Imac and then install it on the netbook.  However, I am not sure if I follow the instruction guide for the OS of the netbook (windows xp) or the Imac I am using to download and convert it to the flash drive.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Even though my first mac was an SE, I don't use them much now, so I'll just stick with a windows to ubuntu approach. Assuming your netbook boots, just download the ubuntu iso, go to [PenDriveLinuxInstallerPage](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/liveusb-install-live-usb-creator/) and use that. As to which ubuntu (32/64 bit) to install, that is a little more complicated. Most "netbooks" run the Intel Atom cpu, so this might help: [Intel Atom Cpu List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom) you can also check to see which version of windows (32/64 bit) you are running as a guide.

If figuring out which image to download proves too much, just try one, and when you boot select 'Try Ubuntu' if it works you'll be ok.